# How do I evaluate this integral $\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{x}{1-ix^2}}\cdot\arctan(\sqrt{i}\cdot x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate the definite integral:$$\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{x}{1-ix^2}}\cdot\arctan(\sqrt{i}\cdot x)$$

And similarly:

$$\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{x}{1-i^{2/3}x^2}}\cdot\arctan({i^{1/3}}\cdot x)$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{x}{1-i^{2/4}x^2}}\cdot\arctan({i^{1/4}}\cdot x)\cdots$$

Are these integrals even evaluable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command of Mathematica 13.3.1 on Windows 10

```
Integrate[x/(1 - I*x^2)*ArcTan[Sqrt[I]*x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

gives an analytic answer $\frac{1}{24} \left(2 \pi ^2+3 \left(2 \text{Li}_2\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) \left(1+(-1)^{3/4}\right)\right)+2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left((1+i)-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)+2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{(1+i)+\sqrt{2}}\right)+2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2 i}{(1+i)+\sqrt{2}}\right)+\log ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{2}+(-1-i)\right)\right)+\log ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} i \left(\sqrt{2}+(1+i)\right)\right)+2 \log \left(1+(-1)^{3/4}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}+(1-i)\right)\right)-2 \log \left(1-(-1)^{3/4}\right) \left(-\log (4)+\log \left(-\sqrt{2}+(1-i)\right)+\log \left((1+i)+i \sqrt{2}\right)\right)+2 \log \left(1+(-1)^{3/4}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left((1+i)-i \sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right)\right)$ which is confirmed numerically by

```
NIntegrate[x/(1 - I*x^2)*ArcTan[Sqrt[I]*x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

$$ 0.1194\, +0.240341 i$$

Comment: Thank you :) , I was expecting a neat result tho :)

Comment: More simplified: $$\frac{1}{32} \left(4 \text{Li}_2\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)-16 \text{Li}_2\left(-i \left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-i \pi  \ln \left(12-8 \sqrt{2}\right)+\ln (16) \coth
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the antiderivative and let $x\sqrt i=t$ to face
$$I=i\int \frac{ t }{t^2-1}\tan ^{-1}(t)\,dt=\frac i2\int \left(\frac 1{t+1}+ \frac 1{t-1}\right)\tan ^{-1}(t)\,dt$$
$$\int\frac {\tan ^{-1}(t) } {t+a} \,dt=\int\frac {\tan ^{-1}(u-a) } {u} \,du$$

Use now
$$\tan ^{-1}(v)=\frac{i}{2}\log \left(-\frac{v+i}{v-i}\right)$$

Comment: "Expand the logarithm"  is a wrong way: for complex values $\log\left(\frac a b \right) \neq \log(a)-\log(b)$.